# Protractor test + manage order of execution

Tags: promise, protractor

I have a Protractor test which looks like

```
pageObject1.method1();
pageObject1.method2();
pageObject2.method1();
expect(pageObject2.method2());
let allDataList = pageObject2.method3();
expect(allDataList.includes('test1')).toBeTruthy();
```

How do I make sure that the call to `pageObject2.method3()` happens before the next expect call? `method3()` returns an array of the text of all span elements.

Comment: Are you using async and await in your method3()  ? please share method3 template

Comment: method3 `getCurrDataAcsGrps(): Array<string>{ let allGroupsList = new Array(); this.currAcsGrpList.each(function(element,index){ element.getText().then(function(text) { //console.log(index, text); allGroupsList.push(text); }); }); return allGroupsList; }`

Comment: method3 - getting values of all span elements into an array

Comment: tried async/await but it was giving different errors

Comment: async getCurrDataAcsGrps(): Array<string>{ 
 let allGroupsList = new Array(); 
 await this.currAcsGrpList.each( async=> (element,index){ 
  await element.getText().then(async=> (text) 
  { 
   //console.log(index, text); 
   await allGroupsList.push(text); 
  }); 
 });
 return allGroupsList; 
}

Comment: Add Async and wait like above

Answer (score 0):

This case you need to use promises

**Way-1:**

```
await pageObject1.method2();
await pageObject2.method1();
expect(pageObject2.method2());
let allDataList = await pageObject2.method3();
expect(allDataList.includes('test1')).toBeTruthy();
```

[Description On await](https://javascript.info/async)

**Way-2:**

```
pageObject1.method2().then(function() {
    pageObject2.method1().then(function() {
        expect(pageObject2.method2());
        pageObject2.method3().then(function(allDataList) {
            expect(allDataList.includes('test1')).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried Way2 but getting error -- Property 'then' does not exist on type 'string[]'.ts(2339). Method3 is like this `getCurrDataAcsGrps(): Array<string>{
        
        let allGroupsList = new Array();
        
        this.currAcsGrpList.each(function(element,index){
            element.getText().then(function(text) {
                //console.log(index, text);
                allGroupsList.push(text);
            });
        });

        return allGroupsList;
    }`

Comment: for that, you need to return the promise from your function. By default, all the protractor functions will return a promise.